# How to get count of consecutive number greater than 0 in string using T-SQL Script

Tags: sql, string

I want to count the consecutive number of string that is greater than 0

e.g 320244434321 : Result is 9 (244434321)

e.g 320244434 : Result is 6 (244434)

e.g 321244430 : Result is 8  (32124443)

e.g 32012076: Result is 2 (32,12,76)

e.g 320120761: Result is 3 (761)

Comment: . . Why are you asking these questions?  They are all related.  I could imagine that this is homework, but SQL Server is not the best tool to for this type of string manipulation.

Comment: I re-created it because there's missing in my sample. That's why, Thanks!

Comment: Thank Gordon Linoff. I already got it. :)

Comment: @iisaactajolosa . . . I'm asking more generally why you are asking these question and why you want to solve them in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Declare @col char(25)

Declare @col1 char(1)

Declare @col2 char(1)

Declare @col3 char(1)

Declare @dpd bigint

SET @col = '320244434321'

SELECT MAX(cons)from(

SELECT

```
value as val,LEN(value) as cons
```

FROM

```
STRING_SPLIT(@col, '0')
```

) ZZ